# Encrypt PNG image contents in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, png

I would like to **encrypt the contents of PNG file** (not the header) in PHP.

After encryption (RSA) the size of IDAT chunk (containing informations about pixels) changes. So I thought of manually changing those binary data (length of chunk, whole chunk and checksum). Specific informations such as width, height, color depth would remain the same (unencrypted).

**Just wondering if there is a function that creates the whole header for me, and enables to insert binary data as the contents** (counts the checksum so the image is properly displayed) or I have to do it by myself?

Comment: why not just encrypt the whole file? what's the advantage of leaving parts of it unencrypted?

Comment: I guess you want the header to remain valid? I'd be inclined to do it this way: decompress the image into an array of (r,g,b,a) 32-bit integers, apply an encryption algorithm to the block such that another valid image is created, then write that image to a PNG. To all intents and purposes, the new image is just an image - but of course it will look like noise, and will need decrypting to get the original image back.

Comment: @Spudley: [Steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)

Comment: The point is that when you encrypt the contents of an image using RSA (or ElGamal) and display it, your eye will still be able to detect the overall outline of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Recently i have done something similar in C++. Instead of altering *IDAT* I added custom chunk (named eg. *xRSA*) with compressed and encrypted image (encryption like that is application specific anyway).

I was able to initially save image (gray background and text informing that this image is encrypted) in *PNG* using 3rd party library. Then I appended this file with custom chunk (bearing in mind *IEND* chunk).

Following this way in PHP you could generate background (maybe not exactly gray but some noise to look cooler) using [imagecreatetruecolor()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) (GD generally) and then add original encrypted image in custom chunk.

Sorry for my english, I hope i would help.